# Where condition based on another condition in postgesql 13

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm using postgresql 13
and wanted to know if this is possible
let's say i have 4 columns : id | name | first_date  | second_date
I wanted to do where condition :

```
select * from my_table where 
if the second_date field null "where first_date=today"
if the second_date field is not null "where second_date=today"
```

Maybe someone know? Thankyou in advance

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Looks like you want `case`.

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` returns the first argument that is not NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE coalesce(second_date, first_date) = current_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the idea of using coalesce is already been used in first answer, here is another approach I may suggest:

```
select * 
  from my_table where 
 where (second_date is null and first_date = today)
    or second_date = today;
```